# Equation with logarithms, why it can't be solved?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find the -3 dB frequency of a filter in Mathematica. Yet, my code doesn't seem to work as it produces imaginary values for the frequency.

```
Tfilter=(9.36*^6 + 44226.*s + 9.477*s^2)/(2.35521*^9 + 495801.*s + 9.477*s^2)
Eqn1 = 20*Log[10, Abs[Tfilter /. s -> I*2*Pi*f]] == -3
Solve[Eqn1, f]
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any additional command I shall give to Mathematica?

Comment: `FindRoot[Eqn1,{f,1}]` instantly returns `{f->7530.29}` Please check that VERY carefully to make certain that is correct. Perhaps `Plot[Log[10,Abs[Tfilter/.s->I*2*Pi*f]]+3/20,{f,0,10^4}]` will give you some useful insight.

Comment: @Bill thank you! Yes I have plotted the graph already so I knew the frequency was around that :)

Comment: This also does the job: `Solve[Eqn1 && f \[Element] Reals, f] `

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Tfilter = (9.36*^6 + 44226.*s + 9.477*s^2)/(2.35521*^9 + 495801.*s + 
       9.477*s^2) // Rationalize // Simplify;
```

Since `f` is real, use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to eliminate [`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html)

```
Eqn1 = 20*Log[10, Abs[Tfilter /. s -> I*2*Pi*f]] == -3 // ComplexExpand // 
   Simplify;

sol = Solve[Eqn1, f, Reals] // N

(* {{f -> -7530.29}, {f -> 7530.29}} *)
```